# RichTextBox: increase top space between border and text

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, c#-4.0, richtextbox

I am searching for a way to increase the space between the top border and the text in a WPF RichTextBox.

I hope, someone can help me, how can I do this. - Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the Padding property (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.padding.aspx).

Here is some example code that page provides:

```
    void ChangePadding(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (btn11.Padding.Left == 5.0)
        {
            btn11.Padding = new Thickness(2.0);
            btn11.Content = "Control Padding changes from 5 to 2.";
        }
        else
        {
            btn11.Padding = new Thickness(5.0);
            btn11.Content = "Padding";
        }
    }
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Add the padding option to the XAML:

```
<RichTextBox Padding="0, 20, 0, 0">
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.padding.aspx